# Restrict parameter in Rails route to INT(11) range

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

Problem: I keep getting this kind of exceptions when API clients send requests with parameters that exceed the maximum of 2147483647 to my Rails 4.2.4 app:

> RangeError: 1446629302683 is out of range for
>   ActiveRecord::Type::Integer with limit 4

The database is MySQL and the numeric type of the column is INT(11), so I was thinking of restricting the range of accepted parameters directly in the route, e.g.

```
get 'movies/:id(.:format)' => 'movies#show', constraints: { id: /.../ }
```

How could I define the range of 4 bytes as Regex expression here? Or is there a smarter approach to this?

Comment: Why do you want to use regex? You know the limit exactly, so just check if the parameter is below the limit.

Comment: How would you express such a condition in the route directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use **8 bytes integer** (**bigint**) instead of 4 bytes integer, rather than restricting the ids in routes.

Declare it this way in your migration file with (`limit: 8` option):

```
add_column :movies, :id, :integer, limit: 8
```

This will give your `id` a limit upto `9223372036854775807` where as the limit with 4 bytes integer is `2147483647`.

See this post for some more information on [bigint in Rails migrations, and what :limit means for column migrations](http://makandracards.com/makandra/15027-how-to-create-columns-like-bigint-or-longtext-in-rails-migrations-and-what-limit-means-for-column-migrations).

But, if you **really** want to use regex to restrict ids upto bigint limit (`9223372036854775807`), then here is the regex for that:

```
\b([1-9][0-9]{0,17}|[1-8][0-9]{18}|9([01][0-9]{17}|2([01][0-9]{16}|2([0-2][0-9]{15}|3([0-2][0-9]{14}|3([0-6][0-9]{13}|7([01][0-9]{12}|20([0-2][0-9]{10}|3([0-5][0-9]{9}|6([0-7][0-9]{8}|8([0-4][0-9]{7}|5([0-3][0-9]{6}|4([0-6][0-9]{5}|7([0-6][0-9]{4}|7([0-4][0-9]{3}|5([0-7][0-9]{2}|80[0-7]))))))))))))))))\b
```

This regex is generate by [Utility Mill](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range) and I tested it on [rubular](http://rubular.com/).

So, using the above regex, your route becomes:

```
get 'movies/:id(.:format)' => 'movies#show', constraints: { id: /\b([1-9][0-9]{0,17}|[1-8][0-9]{18}|9([01][0-9]{17}|2([01][0-9]{16}|2([0-2][0-9]{15}|3([0-2][0-9]{14}|3([0-6][0-9]{13}|7([01][0-9]{12}|20([0-2][0-9]{10}|3([0-5][0-9]{9}|6([0-7][0-9]{8}|8([0-4][0-9]{7}|5([0-3][0-9]{6}|4([0-6][0-9]{5}|7([0-6][0-9]{4}|7([0-4][0-9]{3}|5([0-7][0-9]{2}|80[0-7]))))))))))))))))\b
/ }
```

Comment: Exceptions would still get thrown if API clients send requests with (invalid) IDs greater than 9223372036854775807 ...

Comment: @Boris Look at my updated answer where I showed you how to do that using regex. Let me know if that helps or if you have any other question.

Comment: Thanks, pointing me to the _regex_for_range_ generator was the solution. In my case the routes becomes:
`get 'movies/:id(.:format)' => 'movies#show', constraints: { id: /1[-9][-9][-9][-9][-9][-9][-9][-9][-9]|20[0-9]{8}|21[0-3][0-9]{7}|214[0-6][0-9]{6}|2147[0-3][0-9]{5}|21474[0-7][0-9]{4}|214748[0-2][0-9]{3}|2147483[0-5][0-9]{2}|21474836[0-3][0-9]|214748364[0-7]|[2-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]{3}|[1-9][0-9]{4}|[1-9][0-9]{5}|[1-9][0-9]{6}|[1-9][0-9]{7}|[1-9][0-9]{8}/ }`

Comment: You are welcome. Gald I could help you solve your problem.

Comment: Figured the [Regex range generator](https://tonicdev.com/npm/regex_for_range) I used for the expression above is buggy! [A Python script](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/534137-generate-a-regular-expression-to-match-an-arbitrar/) yielded an expression which seems valid but far too long to post here.